# How to create a work item in Azure Boards using service hooks in the DevOps Projects

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

So in my organization, we have two different projects, Say Project-C and Project-D as follows:

```
https://dev.azure.com/SomeOrganisation/Project-C 
https://dev.azure.com/SomeOrganisation/Project-D
```

I want to create a work item e.g, a user story in Project-C Boards automatically when an artifact is released in Project-D artifacts. The trigger could be the publishing of the artifact or a successful pipeline build before the publish.

I have tried **Power Automate** and it works fine. When the Build is completed in Project-D pipeline, it generates a Work Item ticket in Project-C Boards but I want to achieve the same thing by using facilities within Azure DevOps.

I have looked around in Service Hooks and Service Connections but these facilities do not really provide the functionality. I have looked around the **Web-Hooks** feature, the **actions** can not POST the same JSON content required by Work Item API.

Ironically Service Hooks can be used to create tickets to Trello but not Azure Boards itself. Can it be done by using only Azure DevOps internal facilities? I really do not want to use Power Automate platform unless there exists no other solution. Any help is appreciated.